# Export multiple pdf files from processing library

Tags: java, processing, word-cloud

I need to use processing library, more specifically [WordCram](http://wordcram.org/), to take output multiple PDF files. I do not want to use any applets, and PApplets of Processing library.

I am looking this reference [page](http://processing.org/reference/libraries/pdf/index.html) for taking only a PDF output,

```
import processing.pdf.*;

PGraphics pdf = createGraphics(300, 300, PDF, "output.pdf");
pdf.beginDraw();
pdf.line(50, 50, 250, 250);
pdf.dispose();
pdf.endDraw();
```

And this is the code for the WordCram,

```
new WordCram(this)
    .fromWords(getWords(fromFile))
    .withFont("Sawasdee")
    .drawAll();
```

As far as I understand from this code, the WordCram constructor takes the input, `this`, is the class inherited by `PApplet`.

How am I going to use WordCram without having any PApplet?

Comment: So I guess you are writing in java and not the Processing IDE? Why do you not want to use a papplet? You don't have to do anything with it, just generate it for the library to latch on and do whatever it needs like here: http://wordcram.org/2011/04/28/new-daily-wordcram-to-pdf/ Otherwise, you would have to start pulling stuff out of the source code to get only the functions you need. My guess would be an instance of WordCramEngine in here: https://github.com/danbernier/WordCram/blob/master/src/wordcram/WordCram.java would be enough

Comment: @PetrosKoutsolampros any idea about how to do the hack?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this directly from WordCram.

1. Make a PDF graphics context, like you have above.
2. Make a WordCram for the sketch, but use the [`toCanvas`](http://danbernier.github.io/WordCram/javadoc/wordcram/WordCram.html#toCanvas%28processing.core.PGraphics%29) method to render to the PDF graphics context.
3. Advance to the next page.
4. Make another WordCram.

Note that this seems to render the pages in reverse order: last page first.

I was able to render a PDF successfully with this sample sketch:

```
import processing.pdf.*;
import wordcram.*;

// Make a PDF graphics context
PGraphics pdf = createGraphics(300, 300, PDF, "output.pdf");
pdf.beginDraw();
pdf.background(30);

// Make a WordCram for the sketch, but use the `toCanvas` method 
// to render to the PDF graphics context
new WordCram(this).
  fromWebPage("http://nytimes.com").
  toCanvas(pdf).
  withColor(color(225)).
  drawAll();

// Advance to the next page
((PGraphicsPDF)pdf).nextPage();

// Make another WordCram
pdf.background(225);
new WordCram(this).
  fromWebPage("http://nytimes.com").
  toCanvas(pdf).
  withColor(color(30)).
  drawAll();

pdf.dispose();
pdf.endDraw();

exit();
```